# Methods of measuring speed of anemometer

Tags: speed, frequency-measurement, velocity

I enjoy DIY, but to keep things simple I purchased an anemometer cupset (3 cups). I feel that a magnetic reed switch would get "bounce" at higher speeds and I was thinking of a disk with a slot, and sensing with an LED/photoresistor pair. Would the photoresistor be fast enough? Or would I need something like a phototransistor? 
Are there even better ways while keeping with the KISS (Keep it simple stupid) principle?
Also, how do I convert rotation pulses into MPH?
Note: I live in Florida and as long as my tower (20 feet tall) stands, I might be recording hurricane force winds.

Comment: Budget for KISS?

Comment: Maybe around $20.00.

Comment: Simply debounce the reed switch in software.  Or if you like you can use a hall sensor.  Conversion of measurements is off-topic here, converting pulse interval to tangential velocity of the cups is simple math, but the conversion of cup velocity to wind speed is much more complex and must be determined for a given design.

Comment: To calibrate for MPH, you can take it out in car, maybe in parking lot on non-windy day. Then hold it out of window (will need helper obviously!) and correlate speed of rotation with speed of car. Roughly wind speed that anemometer experiences will be close to speed of car.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I forgot about hall sensors. If I remember correctly, it would be fast enough even in high winds.

Comment: Hall sensors, photodiodes/phototransistors will all be fast enough for any concievable condition, a photoresistor is likely to be too slow for more than a few revs per second, and are far less on/off than the alternatives, so you'd need some level sensing rather than relying on the Schmitt levels on a digital input. I'd choose a Hall sensor.

Comment: Stick a small magnet to the anemometer and use your phone's magnetometer with a plotting app. Here's an example: https://www.amazon.com/Vaavud-Wind-Speed-Meter-Smartphone/dp/B00EBCCCFE

Comment: @tomnexus, It's going at the top of a 20 foot tower. I dont want to leave my phone up there!

Comment: Sure, use a magnetometer breakout board instead. But if you aren't getting the digital sensors to work, an analogue one might help. It needs more signal processing but doesn't need such precise alignment.

Comment: @tomnexus, That's probably a great idea, but it seems a little "over the top" for my little setup. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Remember an anemometer does NOT have a linear response to extremes of wind speed. Below a certain speed friction in the bearings will make it sluggish. At some very high RPM friction and heat in the bearings will bog it down.

Comment: @Sparky256 , That is some info I did not know! I wonder if it is significant enough to have to account for somehow? Do you know any ways it is accounted for?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping optical components clean will be difficult on your 20ft tower, so I think a magnetic switch is the way to go. A solid-state Hall effect switch like this will be cheap and reliable:
https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Diodes-Incorporated/AH3362Q-P-B?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvhQj7WZhFIALYUm%252b6RWDedmaZuFNup%252bZqbCHvIWSV%2fzw%3d%3d

A solid-state Hall effect switch like that is the standard for this purpose (used in motor encoders, etc). It's more reliable than a reed switch over time, and has built-in hysteresis so you won't need to worry about switch bounce.

Use a microcontroller to get pulses per second. (In the code, you would actually measure "seconds between pulses" or, to reduce noise, "seconds between 4 pulses", and take 1/that.) You can calibrate against a commercial anemometer, or hold your anemometer far out the window of a car driving at a known speed.

Comment: This sounds like a solid idea, thanks for taking the time to help me!

Comment: I do have two unused Arduinos, but I need to learn how to program them. This old dog still wants to learn some new tricks.